how to Encode multiple video files in multiple folders
how to encode multiple video files (different types)
in one main folder with multiple subfolders
to h265 with new name?
so i found this:
@echo off
set "_x=compressed"

for /r %%i in (*.mkv, *.mp4, *.mov) do ffmpeg -i "%%~fi" -vcodec libx265 -crf 24  "%%~dpni%_x%.mp4"`

BUT, this command also encode the first processed file again,
from
original.mkv
to
original_compressed
and again to:
original_compressedcompressed
how to avoid this? to run each file found whatever it is mkv or mp4 or avi only once?

Remove *.mp4 from the for loop or save the compressed files in another folder.

but some of the original files already in mp4 format, so if i do that, the script will skip them (or overwrite)

Generally, this has little to do with ffmpeg, and is more about getting the right list of files handed over to something, or making sure the list of files does not included files just created. Something as simple as setting the target directory elsewhere would solve this, for instance.

Also, you might be able to rename the source mp4 files without impacting them, and then do as Toto suggests.

i see, i did find a command for this, although longer, i supposed i can use it and then copy/cut past it to the original root folder to place it back where i want, thanks,
not enough place for the new code in here to paste it
